# extjs4 tree panel in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs4

in my app ,i want to create some function like extjs4 api,when i click the left tree menu, the content will show in the right.some code list below:
left tree menu code:

```
var tree_panel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            listeners: {
    'itemclick': function( grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
             url: 'code/list.js',
             success: function(response){
                show_tip_message("success!")
             },
             failure: function(response){
                  show_tip_message("false!")
             }
         });
      }
    }
```

codecontroller code(codecontroller.rb)

```
   def list
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
   end
end
```

codeview code(list.js.erb)

```
  var m_work_space = Ext.getCmp('work-space');
    m_work_space.removeAll();
    m_work_space.add(m_codegrid);
    m_work_space.doLayout();
```

however when i click the tree item, it pop out notice success ,but the work-space doesn't refresh ,why? any help will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add your updating code in your success callback?

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function( grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'code/list.js',
            success: function(response){
                var m_work_space = Ext.getCmp('work-space'),
                    m_codegrid = response.responseText;

                m_work_space.removeAll();
                m_work_space.add(m_codegrid);
                m_work_space.doLayout();

                show_tip_message("success!")
            },
            failure: function(response){
                show_tip_message("false!")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thx， i find why, although i got the js code, however the js code don't execute. you can also use eval() function